# how can I make highstock flags stay put

Tags: highcharts

In [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cheenu2/5pXfM/) I'd like the little green circles to stay put when hovered over.

In HighStock, when hovering over flags, how can I make them stay put (without trying to come to foreground)?

```
//
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you cannot use points with the same x value inside single serie. You need to use separated series like here: http://jsfiddle.net/5pXfM/5/

```
{
        type: 'flags',
        data: [{
            x: Date.UTC(2011, 2, 10),
            title: ' ',
            text: 'Do not move'
        }],
        onSeries: 'dataseries',
        shape: 'circlepin',
        color: '#5F86B3',
        fillColor: 'rgba(50, 255, 50, .75)',
        y: -10,
        stackDistance: 5
    },{
        type: 'flags',
        data: [{
            x: Date.UTC(2011, 2, 10),
            title: ' ',
            text: 'Do not move'
        }],
        onSeries: 'dataseries',
        shape: 'circlepin',
        color: '#5F86B3',
        fillColor: 'rgba(50, 255, 50, .75)',
        y: -30,
        stackDistance: 5

    }
```

Comment: My usecase is several points with same x value (news articles for that day). Doesn't make sense to add a series for each data point.